# Teaching mathematics at the college level,

Tags: mathematics, teaching, community-college

Can I teach a college level math course at a community college with secondary mathematics certification.

Comment: I think this would probably be possible; look at some job postings; I suppose a lot depends on what sort of competition you would be facing for the position.

Answer (score 6):

It is my understanding that secondary mathematics certification and community college teaching are "disjoint sets," such that having the certification is neither required nor directly helpful to teach at a community college.  I am confident that having such a certification will not disadvantage you in any way, but that's probably not what you're asking.  If you mean "Can I teach a college level math course at a community college with a secondary mathematics certification **instead of [something else]**?" then the answer is: maybe not, but if you are interested you should probably ask.

I have only indirect knowledge of the community college teaching community, and my understanding is that the parameters of the job vary heavily by region and institution.  For instance, in some parts of the country most community college faculty have terminal degrees (generally a PhD), whereas in others this is rare.  The requirements to teach one course may well be different from those of full-time faculty.  I would expect that having a master's degree in a related field would be sufficient for you to teach college-level math courses at *many* community colleges.  If you only have a bachelor's degree, then that might not be enough...or then again it might.

At my large state research university (UGA), we often find ourselves wanting to run a few more sections of precalculus and calculus and having to hire temporary (or "adjunct") faculty very close to the last minute.  It is my understanding that the necessity of covering classes can result in a flexibility in terms of hiring.  So I think that there is a good shot that someone who looks competent to teach course X will eventually get to teach course X at some community college if they are sufficiently persistent.

Answer (score 5):

Pete Clark's answer seems solid. Here is a specific example to back it up: CUNY is one of the systems that most generally requires a PhD and published research even for community-college professors. But adjuncts can still be hired with only a bachelor's degree in the subject. (The teaching certification is, indeed, a non-issue.) From a current CUNY job posting for adjunct math instructors:

> QUALIFICATIONS
>
> For Adjunct Assistant Professor: Ph.D. degree in area(s) of experience
>   or equivalent. Also required is the ability to teach successfully.
>
> For Adjunct Lecturer: Bachelor's degree in area(s) of expertise, and
>   the ability to teach successfully. Master's Degree strongly preferred.

[That's currently here](http://cuny.jobs/brooklyn-ny/adjunct-lecturer-or-adjunct-assistant-professor-mathematics/0206B7F45AEF4956AE554BE9C4588B59/job/), but the link will probably age out quickly.